# Java―MalformedInputException with BufferedReader

Tags: java, file-io, mysql

I am a bit new to Java, so I have absolutely no Idea how to fix the following Problem. I am coding a small cli program to processes mysql-dump-files. In the (hopefully) last Junit-test a »bigger« (990.3kB) Mysql-file is processed and only this file gives this error:

```
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

Neither the error message no the description from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/MalformedInputException.html) give my a hint hot to fix it. If I open the file with Kate this error is shown:

[image: screenshot of the error-message from kate]

Right now the code* looks like:

```
String line;
BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(in, Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ) );

while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null )
{
   //processing stuff goes here
}
```

*calling `reader.readLine()` is what causes the error.

I guess I need to change to way how to read the file, but that is just guessing and hope for some good help here. If anybody has a Link to a resource which gives some background Information for this would be very fine, too.

Thanks in ahead!

**EDIT:**

After some searching I could manage to make Java »read that file« by changing the above code to:

```
BufferedReader reader = 
    new BufferedReader( 
        new InputStreamReader( 
            new FileInputStream( in.toFile() ) ) );
```

Is this the way to work around potential charset problems? Will this lead me to other potential issues? I would really appreciate some explanation about the details…

Comment: Would be nice to give a reason for the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with *Kate*.

*Settings -> Configure -> Open/Save*

*Set:Line Length Limit to zero.*

Its a known [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kile/+bug/997004) with other KDE editors as well.

**Edit**

Missed the java exception. The probable cause for that exception is you are *not* getting a *UTF-8* encoded file.

> MalformedInputException thrown when an input byte sequence is not
>   legal for given charset, or an input character sequence is not a legal
>   sixteen-bit Unicode sequence.

Comment: no. The reason why I asked this question is because of an Error throw by java, I just posted that screenshot because it probably improves the description.

Comment: Sorry missed that. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for your update, but how can I read that file, no matter if corrupted or not?